# Catch KeyUp Event on WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

I attempt to catch F5 on `System.Windows.Forms` for that I wrote:

```
partial class MainForm
{
   (...)
   this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.MainForm_KeyUp);
   (...)
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    (...)

    private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("MainForm_KeyUp");
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
        {
            RefreshStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

But my event catching looks not working.

Do you know how to cactch EventKey on `System.Windows.Forms` ?

Comment: You can first try testing it by doing something like this.... throw new Exception(e.KeyCode.ToString()); .... Maybe that will give you a clue about what you keycode you should use. Also, make sure to use e.Handled = true;

Comment: @ismellike and Grant Winney, adding an exception or breakpoint is not doing something more. Even I didn't got something from my Log box. That confirms event is not caught at all.

Comment: @Grant Winney, "What is this.KeyUp += ... in?" this is autogenerated by Visual Studio when I link from my designer view `KeyUp` event to `MainForm_KeyUp`. So that is in `InitializeComponent()` called by constructor of `MainForm`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`KeyPreview` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) of the Form must be set to true.

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus.