# How Catch Keyup Event In User Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keyup

I want to catch keyup event of parent form in a usercontrol. I use ProcessCmdKey but it just give me keydown event and it doesn't raise in keyup event. How can I do it?

**Update:**  I want to catch keyup event of form. because Control.KeyUp raised when control is focused.

```
public partial class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    public ExtendedButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYUP && keyData == (Keys.NumPad0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604633/catch-keyup-event-on-winform-c-sharp

Comment: @user2864740 I want to use keyup event in usercontrol not in the form

Comment: There is [Control.KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) .. still not sure what the complication is for.

Comment: @user2864740 I want to catch keyup event of of form. because Control.KeyUp raised when control is focused.

Comment: You might have keep a list of Controls you want to bubble down to.  Kinda like how programs keeps all Windows' Title Bar active no matter which one has focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can create handler for Parent Form KeyUp in UserControl's OnHandleCreated override method.

Try this code

```
Form parentForm = null;
private void ParentForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("HI");
}

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    if (DesignMode)
        return;

    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    object parent = this;
    while (true)
    {
        parent = ((Control)parent).Parent;
        if (parent.GetType().BaseType.Name == "Form")
            break;
    }
    parentForm = (Form)parent;
    parentForm.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(this.ParentForm_KeyUp);
    parentForm.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(this.ParentForm_KeyUp);
}
```

Comment: what is happening? Getting any error? Have you set the `KeyPreview` property of your parent form to true?

Comment: yes I set KeyPreview property. no error but keyup event doesn't raised.

Comment: have you tried to debug the code? Is `OnHandleCreated` event getting fired or not? user control unable to create handler for parent form key up event then it will not be fired. try to place break point on `parentForm = (Form)parent;` line and debug it what value in stored in `parent` object.

Comment: OnHandleCreated fired and and the value of parentForm is true. but events doesn't fire.